# how to use ImageIdentify without internet access and without having to login to WRI accunt?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I am not using a Wolfram Alpha command. I am trying the command `ImageIdentify` for first time. I am surprised to find I get popup window asking me to login to Wolfram research account on the cloud somewhere to run the command on my PC?

Is it possible to run this command without internet access. But if internet access is really needed, why does one also need to have cloud account to run this command? Will the account be used to charge for using the command? Does this command require cloud credits to use?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I never had a command before asking me to login to WRI account in order to run it. ps. I do have my preferences set to allow Wolfram access to the internet.

**Update**

To answer comment in answer below. When I use the command

```
 net=NetModel["Wolfram ImageIdentify Net for WL 11.1"]
```

It is also asking me to login to the cloud. I restarted Mathematica also, and it made no effect. It ask for an account. Here is movie

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can run any commands that use the entity system without Internet access. (Except, perhaps, a specific example due caching.)

Comment: @C.E. I do not know what entity system is. I do have internet access. I run this command as I was connected to the internet. But why does one need a cloud account to run a Mathematica command?

Comment: Of course you know what entities are, e.g. `Entity["City", {"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]`. This is what `ImageIdentify` returns. I for one don't think Mathematica ships with all of its entities, which must be millions. Shipping with the entities would be like shipping with all of Wolfram Alpha. Ergo, Internet access is required at least to do anything with the returned result. But looking Zviovich's answer, maybe there is a way to at least get the entities corresponding to the image without Internet.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Version 11.2, you can download the Image Identify netmodel to your computer and run it off-line.

```
(*With Network Connection*)
net=NetModel["Wolfram ImageIdentify Net for WL 11.1"]
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

You can proceed to save the object for future use as a persistent object.

```
PersistentValue["netImageIdentify","Local"]=net
```

When off line, you can use the  neural network.

```
img = Import["D:\\user\\Documents\\dog.jpg"]
net[img]
(*Entity["Concept", "Beagle::2bdvt"]*)
```

[image]

There are other image identification networks available to download. Check out the Netmodel functionality.

Comment: Thanks.  But the command `net=NetModel["Wolfram ImageIdentify Net for WL 11.1"]` itself is asking me to create a WRI cloud account !  So I need a cloud account to download software so I can use a command that does not require me to have a cloud account? but +1 for the information provided. I was hoping for something that does not require an account.

Comment: Interesting. I logged out from my account, closed the session, open it again and tried with the following model net = NetModel["Inception V1 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"], it downloaded it without calling for my wolfram id. Then I run it against the picture and brought the entity without using the account

Comment: Then why is it asking me to login to Wolfram Cloud? I do not know. But it does ask. I will try again now by restarting Mathematica. FYI, added movie showing it is still asking me to login to account. (so you believe me :)